# Alternating between \itemize and \overprint to display text and images

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm trying to create a presentation using beamer. And I would like to display an image after each item at the same position.

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{itemize}
    \item Macro\\ 
    \uncover<2>
    \item Micro\\ 
    \uncover<3> 
    \item Nano 
\begin{overprint}
    \only<1> {\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{image_1}}
    \only<2> {\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{image_2}} 
    \only<3> {\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{image_3}} 
\end{overprint}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

With this code it first displays the three items and then switches between the images but as stated I'd like to show with each item the corresponding image and most important at the same position (it should be seemless during the presentation).

I also tried it with [itemize](/questions/tagged/itemize) 
and [onlyenv](/questions/tagged/onlyenv). With those two commands the alternating worked but I could not change the position of the images.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve the result I am looking for.

Comment: You should probably move your question to tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If understood the question correctly, you have three items and three images, and you want first item and first image, second item and second image etc., to be displayed. E.g. here with minipage, with uncover to fade out the respective other 2 items.

```
\begin{frame}{Test Slide}
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\uncover<1>{\item Item1}
\uncover<2>{\item Item2}
\uncover<3>{\item Item3}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.49\linewidth}
\includegraphics<1>[width=0.9\linewidth]{image1.eps}
\includegraphics<2>[width=0.9\linewidth]{image2.png}
\includegraphics<3>[width=0.9\linewidth]{omage3.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```